# How to have selected result with different filter with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a data set looks as

```
{"BrandId":"a","SessionId":100,"Method": "POST"}
{"BrandId":"a","SessionId":200,"Method": "PUT"}
{"BrandId":"a","SessionId":200,"Method": "GET"}
{"BrandId":"b","SessionId":300,"Method": "GET"}
```

I would like to count distinct SessionId group by brandid and count where method is POST group by brandid. For the example I mentioned, the expected result is:

```
{"BrandId:"a","countSession":2,"countPOST":1}
{"BrandId:"b","countSession":1,"countPOST":0}
```

I know if I want to count distinct seesionid by brandid, the code is as following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$group: {
            "_id": {
                brand: "$BrandId",
                session: "$SessionId"
            },
            count: {$sum: 1}
    }},
    {$group: {
            _id: "$_id.brand",
           countSession:{$sum:1}
    }}
])
```

If we only need to count post the code is as following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {Method:"POST"}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$BrandId', 
        countPOST:{$sum:1}
   }}
])
```

But I do not combine these two code together, and have result same as the expected result I just mentioned before? anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You will need in your first `$group` stage count the number of  `POST` for distinct `SessionId` and `BrandId` then in your second `$group` stage count distinct `SessionId` and `$sum` total `POST` by `BrandId`

```js
 db.collections.aggregate(
     [ 
         { '$match': {'Method': 'POST' }}, 
         { '$group': { 
                         '_id': { 
                                    'brand': '$BrandId', 
                                    'session': '$SessionId' 
                     },
                         'countPost': { '$sum': 1 }
         }
                     }, 
         { '$group': { 
                         '_id': '$_id.brand', 
                         'countSession': { '$sum': 1 }, 
                         'countPost': { '$sum': '$countPost' }
                     }
         }, 
         { '$project': { 
                           'BrandId': '$_id', 
                           'countPost': 1, 
                           'countSession': 1,
                           '_id': 0 
                       }
         }
    ]
)
```

Output:

```
{ "countSession" : 1, "countPost" : 1, "BrandId" : "b" }
{ "countSession" : 2, "countPost" : 3, "BrandId" : "a" }
```

Comment: Hi, If you use the same example data I mentioned in the question, you can see the result is not match the expected result.

Comment: The code is not correct, because it filter with the data only with POST. There exist some Brand with no POST at all and I still need to count this brand. I need to combine with data of different filter. And this is where I meet a problem.

Comment: @erkpwejropi In your post you said *count distinct SessionId group by brandid and count where method is POST*

Comment: sorry, perhaps I do not use the clear words. I need  count distinct SessionId group by brandid; count where method is POST. and these two thing is separated.  I ask if there is a way to write the two query I offered to  one query. I hope I mentioned it clear this time, otherwise, you can check my expected result.